# assignging text file contents to variable

Tags: vb.net, filesystems, default-value, assign

Stack!

I'm currently trying to code a neat little function in Visual Basic that deletes my entire file system for my program depending on the contents of one text file.

If my text file contains the number 0 by itself, my file system will be deleted. If it contains a 1 by itself, it will not delete the file system and carry on with its pathway of execution.

the problem I'm having is reading the file, then assigning the text file's contents to a variable (string), which then is used in an if statement to decide whether it deletes (then immediately recreates) the file system, or keeps it. Ideally I'd be using this primarily for when the user installs. By default, it is set to 0 so that it clears any stored content, then after creating my directory, the number turns to 1 so that it does not reset my programs content directory.

Here's my code. The first line is giving me difficulties -

Could not find file 'C:\Users\110fa_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Novation_Launchpad_Emulator\Novation_Launchpad_Emulator\bin\Debug\0'.

```
    fileReader = File.ReadAllText(My.Resources.FirstTimeUse)

    If fileReader = "0" Then
        FirstTimeUse = True
    End If
```

If you can help me, that'd be absolutely brilliant. I don't think there's any more information I can give sadly, but everything regarding the function, purpose, and error is there.

Comment: The error message is clear. Do you have that **file** in that exact location? I suspect that `My.Resources.FirstTimeUse` doesn't contain the name of your file, but just the value 0

Comment: @Steve I apologise for the late reply, my computer's network adapter stops working after a few hours. My file is located in the "\bin\New Install" folder of the program. I added it to my resources and it suddenly thinks that it is placed in the "\debug" folder, and thinks it's called "0" (shown in the error, despite being named "FirstTimeInstall"

Comment: Remember that if you give relative paths then they are relative to the location where your executable runs. In a debug session of Visual Studio this is just the bin\debug. However I suggest to clear the solution and rebuild everything

Comment: @Steve would that mean that I should just rebuild the solution? I'm essentially just trying to create a file that changes it's value after the first time the program is ran on another computer so that it does not recreate my filesystem (potentilally deleting user data) after the first execution. - Or is there a simpler way to do that?